# Blackberry 10 Scheduled Task

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Hi I am developing an application like alarm clock that will allows the user to set a time and sound url. And when the time runs out the application should start automatically by playing the sound url. How this can be possible in Blackberry 10.Any one know the answer please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current way to approach this is by using a long-running headless application.

Check [here for more info on headless apps](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/headless_apps/).

Your long-running headless application would run in the background and process any alarms the user sets. You could store the alarms in [QSettings](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qsettings.html).

In the upcoming [OS 10.3 Gold SDK](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/roadmap/), you'll be able to use a short-running headless app with a timer trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am updating my SDK from 10.1 to 10.2.